# C# serial port-picture box problem

Tags: c#, winforms

In C# WinForms I'm writing a program that reads values from serial port and according to the received value it displays an image in picture box: if the value is X, it will display image1 and if the value is Y it will display image2 ... and so on.

When I received  the first value, the program displays the first image v; good, but when the second value is received, no new image is displayed: only the same image displayed even the values changed.. the picturebox didn't change the image.

I try `picturebox.Refresh()` and `picturebox.Invalidate()` but that doesn't work.

Thanks

This is some code that sets images:

```
if (value == "X")
{
    path = "c:\\c#\\image1.png";
    pictureBox1.Invoke(new OutputUpdateDelegate (OutputUpdateCallback1),path);
}

if (value == "Y")
{
    path = "c:\\c#\\image2.png";
    pictureBox1.Invoke(new OutputUpdateDelegate(OutputUpdateCallback1), path);
}

delegate void OutputUpdateDelegate(string data);

private void OutputUpdateCallback1(string data)
{    
   pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(data);
}
```

Comment: Add code that sets the image please. Also, are you sure the code is called?

Comment: this is some code that displays images:

Comment: which code? I don't see anything...

Comment: the code is called and put the new value in the text box but the image dont change...any one can solve the problem, please??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (value == "X")
{
    path = "c:\\c#\\image1.png";
    pictureBox1.Invoke(new OutputUpdateDelegate (OutputUpdateCallback1),path);
}

if (value == "Y")
{
    path = "c:\\c#\\image2.png";
    pictureBox1.Invoke(new OutputUpdateDelegate(OutputUpdateCallback1), path);
}

delegate void OutputUpdateDelegate(string data);

private void OutputUpdateCallback1(string data)
{    
   pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(data);
}
```

I removed some bracket "}" which seemed placed wrong - although not sure because there is not enough source to be sure...

EDIT:

to further diagonse put a breakpoint on `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(data);` and see what the value of data is...